# mac pro going to sleep on nohup

Tags: sleep-wake, ssh

I have the following scenario. I have shell scripts that I want to run remotely on my mac pro, so I ssh in, launch them with nohup, and log out.  I've done this for years on linux based machines, and I just started trying it out on the new mac pro.  However, I find that the mac goes to sleep while these are running, and it takes much longer to finish.  Obviously I can disable sleep in the energy preferences, but there are definitely times when I want it to let it power down.  Is there anything I could do, in terms of a command line argument, that would disable sleep while the process was running?

Answer (score 3):

### caffeinate your scripts

Use the OS X built-in [caffeinate](http://dssw.co.uk/reference/caffeinate.html) command to prevent your Mac going to sleep. `caffeinate` is the recommended way of lodging a temporary restriction against your Mac entering a low power state.

> `caffeinate` creates assertions to alter system sleep behavior. If no
>   assertion flags are specified, caffeinate creates an assertion to
>   prevent idle sleep. If a utility is specified, caffeinate creates the
>   assertions on the utility’s behalf, and those assertions will persist
>   for the duration of the utility’s execution. Otherwise, caffeinate
>   creates the assertions directly, and those assertions will persist
>   until caffeinate exits.

Comment: Very nice indeed!

Answer (score 2):

You can use `pmset` to temporarily prevent mac from going to sleep.

`pmset noidle & PMSETPID=${!};sleep 10; kill $PMSETPID`

Replace `sleep 10` with your command.

You can also write a function and save it to `.bash_profile`.

```
insomnia() {
    pmset noidle &
    PMSETPID=$!
    $($@)
    kill $PMSETPID
}
```

and use it like this:
`$ insomnia sleep 10`

I recommend to use `screen` instead of `nohup`.

Edit: *on newer Macs you should use `caffeinate` as described by Graham Miln. `pmset noidle` still works, but since 10.9 it is marked as "deprecated" in the documentation.*

Answer (score 0):

I made a function inside my ~/`.bash_profile`, like so:

```
# ~/.bash_profile

# wrap ssh so computer doesn't go to sleep
ssh()
{
    echo "caffeinating ssh session..."
    LC_CTYPE= # fix issue with UTF8 on server
    caffeinate -i ssh "$@"
}
```

Now when I use my "common" the ssh command it get wrapped in **caffeinate** therefore keeps the system from going to sleep.

Now when i start a ssh session, i can see `pmset -g` telling me:

```
sleep                10 (sleep prevented by caffeinate)
```